# Multiply trait implementations in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to implement trait IDimTransformer for different generic types of traits IDimOffset0Transformer and IDimOffset1Transformer but compiler give me error

```
trait IDimTransformer {
    fn get_offset_x(&self, x: i32) -> i32;
    fn get_offset_z(&self, z: i32) -> i32;
}

trait IDimOffset0Transformer : IDimTransformer {}
trait IDimOffset1Transformer : IDimTransformer {}

impl<T: IDimOffset0Transformer> IDimTransformer for T {
    fn get_offset_x(&self, x: i32) -> i32 {
        return x;
    }

    fn get_offset_z(&self, z: i32) -> i32 {
        return z;
    }
}

impl<T: IDimOffset1Transformer> IDimTransformer for T {
    fn get_offset_x(&self, x: i32) -> i32 {
        return x - 1;
    }

    fn get_offset_z(&self, z: i32) -> i32 {
        return z - 1;
    }
}
```

Example of use

```
struct Layer {}
impl IDimOffset1Transformer for Layer{}

fn some_func(dim: &impl IDimTransformer, x: i32, z: i32) -> i32 {
    return dim.get_offset_x(x) + dim.get_offset_z(x);
}

fn some_func_1(layer: &Layer, x: i32, z: i32) -> i32 {
    return some_func(layer, x, z);
}
```

Compiler error

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `layer::IDimTransformer`:
  --> src/layer.rs:59:1
   |
49 | impl<T: IDimOffset0Transformer> IDimTransformer for T {
   | ----------------------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
59 | impl<T: IDimOffset1Transformer> IDimTransformer for T {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation
```

Comment: 1) Please add code and error to the question as text, not images. 2) What should your code do for types which implement both `IDimOffset0Transformer` and `IDimOffset1Transformer`? Traits are not mutually exclusive (with the only exception being `Drop` and `Copy`, which are treated specially in compiler).

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Comment: On nightly you can use specialization for this, otherwise you can create wrapper types.

Comment: You cannot have mutually exclusive traits, so it's rhetorically possible that some `T` could implement both `IDimOffset0Transformer` *and* `IDimOffset1Transformer`. Specialization won't help unless you rewrite the bounds so that one is more specific than the other.

Comment: With the `ITrait` naming scheme and other oddities, it looks like you're trying to write C# or Java or something in Rust. This is rarely going to work out the way you want. I can't guess at what your code is doing but having a 3:1 trait/struct ratio in this snippet hints that your abstractions aren't pulling their weight. There's not an obvious solution to the immediate problem, but there are probably dozens of other designs that would work for what you're *really* trying to do; consider [one trait with an associated `const`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=72ae5e4f8af0bff6d06010ed0e381aa8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the pattern you are looking for looks like this in rust:

```rust
trait Transformer {
    fn get_offset_x(x: i32) -> i32;
    fn get_offset_z(z: i32) -> i32;
}

struct Offset0Transformer;

impl Transformer for Offset0Transformer {
    fn get_offset_x(x: i32) -> i32 {
        x
    }

    fn get_offset_z(z: i32) -> i32 {
        z
    }
}

struct Offset1Transformer;

impl Transformer for Offset1Transformer {
    fn get_offset_x(x: i32) -> i32 {
        x - 1
    }

    fn get_offset_z(z: i32) -> i32 {
        z - 1
    }
}

struct Layer { x: i32, z: i32 };

impl Layer {
    fn add_transformed<T: Transformer>(&self) -> i32 {
        T::get_offset_x(self.x) + T::get_offset_z(self.z)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let layer = Layer { x: 5, z: 2 };
    let result = layer.add_transformed::<Offset1Transformer>();
    println!("got: {}", result);
}
```

Most of the time you won't need this though. Thinking through what your code is trying to do and thinking of a simpler way usually gets you smaller better code.